# Sequelize : How to map a custom attribute in a pivot table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got this pivot table, which represents a many to many relationship with the models Person and Movie.

[image: Pivot table schema]

The thing is I want to get the role when I call the movies that get the persons associated. I tried this but it doesn't show the role :

```
models.Movie.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.Person,
        as: 'persons',
        through: {attributes: ["role"]}
    }]
}).then(function(movies) {
    res.json(movies);
});
```

Do I have to specify something in the models for the `role` ?

Comment: did you end up figuring this one out?

Comment: @MichaelSchinis I actually did, see my answer below

Comment: hmm. Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve this by creating a model for the pivot table `movie_person` with the `role` attribute as a string.

```
var MoviePerson = sequelize.define("MoviePerson", {
    role: DataTypes.STRING
},
{
    tableName: 'movie_person',
    underscored: true
});
```

Then in my `Movie` model I added this

```
Movie.belongsToMany(models.Person, {
    through: models.MoviePerson,
    foreignKey: 'movie_id',
    as: 'persons'
});
```

I had to do something obviously similar to this in my Person model and that's it !

Comment: btw with the new version it is possible in a easier way http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of those who will need this, there is a new method called 'magic methods'. I believe you have declared your many-to-many asociation

```
    const movies = Movie.findAll();
    const person = Person.findbyPk(personId);
    const moviesPerson = movies.getPersons(person);
```